# Toast object crashing app

Tags: android

I have this MainActivity that crashes my application instantly. Why is this happening? I tried to substitute the "MainActivity.this" part of the argument with an object of type Context: `Context aContext = getApplicationContext();`, following Google's reference example, with the exact same result.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks much.

```
package com.nactus.questionme;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Button mMadridButton;
    private Button mWrongButton;
    private Toast aToast;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // target the buttons
        mMadridButton = (Button) findViewById(R.string.button_madrid);
        mWrongButton = (Button) findViewById(R.string.button_wrong);

        // set event listeners
        mMadridButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Context context = getApplicationContext();

                // my code goes here
                aToast = Toast.makeText(context, "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

                aToast.show();
            }
        });

        mWrongButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Context context = getApplicationContext();

                // my code goes here
                aToast = Toast.makeText(context, "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

                aToast.show();
            }
        });
    }



}
```

Code updated to reflect suggestions: same crash

Comment: out of curiosity, does it crash right away or only when you press the button?

Comment: @tf.alves, right away

Comment: Ok, read my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
R.string.buttonWrong
```

(parameter for findViewById) it should be:

```
R.id.buttonWrong
```

cause it searches the R.java file, where all information about elements (Buttons, Switches, Layouts) written in XML files are stored.

Comment: `aToast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), R.string.incorrect_toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);` same exact crash

Comment: Weird. So maybe something is wrong with R.string.incorrect_toast? Try to put there some hardcore like "Text"

Comment: So it cannot the problem with Toast. As suggested above, maybe something with the device. I'll check on my device

Comment: Well, I don't know whether this is the reason, but the line: findViewById(R.string.button_wrong);
is probably wrong. Usually parameter of findViewById is something in R.id package (R.id.buttonWrong for button with id buttonWrong in xml file). So maybe after findViewById it points to some strange value and therefore crashes. Try to change to R.id.buttonMadrid and R.id.buttonWrong

Comment: that did it ... the R.id, I'll vote your comment and if you edit the answer I'll be able to accept it.

Comment: You're right about this answer. Wow, it was something so simple that I didn't even noticed! :)

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to use `getApplicationContext()` function.

For example,

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
aToast = Toast.makeText(context, R.string.incorrect_toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
aToast.show();
```

Read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could provide the error log from logcat. But I am assuming here that your applications crashes right away and not when you press the button.
If that is the case, then it might be a NullPointerException caused by the wrong id being fed to the findViewById method. Please check if the supplied ids belong to the activity_main layout.
Either mMadridButton or mWrongButton is null when you set the click listener. Therefore it crashes. The Toast part seems ok as it is!

Comment: [2014-04-03 13:36:25 - ddms] null
java.nio.BufferOverflowException
 at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.put(HeapByteBuffer.java:200)
 at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.movePacket(JdwpPacket.java:235)
 at com.android.ddmlib.Debugger.sendAndConsume(Debugger.java:347)
 at com.android.ddmlib.Client.forwardPacketToDebugger(Client.java:665)
 at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.processClientActivity(MonitorThread.java:344)
 at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:263)

Comment: Check if the device in which you are performing your tests is selected in the "Devices" view. Also perform a "clean project" just to be safe. Can you start the project with the debugger and check where it fails? That logcat error you posted above cannot be right for the code you provided, it just doesn't make sense :)

Comment: logcat is clean, that's the console

Comment: used some breakpoints, it crashes right on here:  ` mMadridButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()` it jumps to here: catch (Exception e) {
            if (!mInstrumentation.onException(activity, e)) {
                throw new RuntimeException(
                    "Unable to start activity " + component
                    + ": " + e.toString(), e);

Answer (score 0):

Don't use this code

```
private Toast aToast;
aToast = Toast.makeText(context, "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
aToast.show();
```

Instead use this single line code

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"test",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: cleaned that object and added your suggestion, got the same crash. I'm starting to think this might be a hardware issue :S?

Comment: build different emulators on android virtual device manager and test your app on different emulators...if same problem is there then the problem is in your code